# sony alpha 6000 camera api responds with outdated (1.0) api list

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

Can connect to sony alpha 6000 via wifi and requesting 'startRecMode' succeeds.
However calling getAvailableApiList after startRecMode only gives a list as of version 1.0. That is, features like setting f number or shutter speed are missing and dont succeed.
Camera firmware is 3.20.

What do I have to do to get a more recent api version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I either had an old version of smart remote app preinstalled on my camera or one that didnt match the camera. After installing the current version by directly connecting the camera with the internet (via wifi) things seem to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 things you can try.

1. First the "getAvailableApiList" function gives you the option to specify a version number as an additional parameter. Maybe you can try running the "getVersions" command to see what versions of the API your camera supports
2. You can try downloading the latest firmware for your device here : https://www.sony.co.uk/electronics/support/e-mount-body-ilce6000-series/ilce-6000

Comment: getVersions only lists '1.0'. I am not sure whether I should update the firmware, because it already is 3.20 (current). Do you suggest to update anyway?

Comment: hmm... I know that certain features are not available depending on the mode your camera is in. For instance movie, still, etc... First off try running the "getSupportedFNumber" and "getSupportedShutterSpeed" methods to see if you camera supports these features. Then try running the "getShootMode" function to see which mode you are in and then try changing the shoot mode and running "getAvailableShutterSpeed" and "getAvailableFNumber"

Comment: A call to getAvailableApiList after startRecMode doesnt list  getSupportedFNumber and  getSupportedShutterSpeed. Calling them returns error 403. Only available shoot mode is 'still'
Trying to set mode to 'movie' fails with error 500.  Calling the application info returns ["Smart Remote Control SR/2.11 \_\_MKN\_\_“,"„2.0.0“]

Comment: hmm... If you are getting an error code 403 then the command is probably not supported on your camera. Perhaps you can try updating your play memories app on your android device though to see if anything changes. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sony.playmemories.mobile

Comment: updating smart remote app on the *camera* solved the problem, see my own answer

Comment: ooops.. Sorry, looks like I missed that. Glad that you found a solution that works!